# for loop with ggplot - error in rep_len(TRUE, nrow(x)) : invalid 'length.out' value

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I am tweaking on a way to calculate and save charts in a certain company style. I found all things I need with the custom options of ggplot but am still stuck to build this into a loop. I have roughly 110 Columns/Variables to apply this to.

My data:

```
test <- structure(list(Intensitaet_Wareneingang = structure(c(Intensitaet_Wareneingang = NA_integer_, 
Intensitaet_Wareneingang = NA_integer_, Intensitaet_Wareneingang = NA_integer_, 
Intensitaet_Wareneingang = NA_integer_, Intensitaet_Wareneingang = NA_integer_, 
Intensitaet_Wareneingang = NA_integer_, Intensitaet_Wareneingang = NA_integer_, 
Intensitaet_Wareneingang = NA_integer_, Intensitaet_Wareneingang = NA_integer_, 
Intensitaet_Wareneingang = NA_integer_, Intensitaet_Wareneingang = NA_integer_, 
Intensitaet_Wareneingang = NA_integer_, Intensitaet_Wareneingang = NA_integer_, 
Intensitaet_Wareneingang = NA_integer_, Intensitaet_Wareneingang = NA_integer_, 
Intensitaet_Wareneingang = NA_integer_, Intensitaet_Wareneingang = NA_integer_, 
Intensitaet_Wareneingang = NA_integer_, Intensitaet_Wareneingang = NA_integer_, 
Intensitaet_Wareneingang = NA_integer_, Intensitaet_Wareneingang = NA_integer_
), .Label = c("sehr gering", "gering", "mittel", "hoch", "sehr hoch", 
"keine Angabe", "NA"), class = "factor"), Zufriedenheit_Wareneingang = c(NA, 
"keine Angabe", "mittel", "hoch", "hoch", "mittel", "hoch", NA, 
"sehr hoch", "keine Angabe", NA, "keine Angabe", "keine Angabe", 
"keine Angabe", "hoch", "hoch", "mittel", "mittel", NA, "mittel", 
NA), Intensitaet_Einlagerung = c(NA, "mittel", "gering", "hoch", 
"hoch", "gering", "sehr hoch", NA, "sehr hoch", "mittel", NA, 
"sehr gering", "sehr gering", "sehr gering", "gering", "sehr hoch", 
"sehr hoch", "mittel", NA, "hoch", NA), Zufriedenheit_Einlagerung = structure(c(Zufriedenheit_Einlagerung = NA_integer_, 
Zufriedenheit_Einlagerung = NA_integer_, Zufriedenheit_Einlagerung = NA_integer_, 
Zufriedenheit_Einlagerung = NA_integer_, Zufriedenheit_Einlagerung = NA_integer_, 
Zufriedenheit_Einlagerung = NA_integer_, Zufriedenheit_Einlagerung = NA_integer_, 
Zufriedenheit_Einlagerung = NA_integer_, Zufriedenheit_Einlagerung = NA_integer_, 
Zufriedenheit_Einlagerung = NA_integer_, Zufriedenheit_Einlagerung = NA_integer_, 
Zufriedenheit_Einlagerung = NA_integer_, Zufriedenheit_Einlagerung = NA_integer_, 
Zufriedenheit_Einlagerung = NA_integer_, Zufriedenheit_Einlagerung = NA_integer_, 
Zufriedenheit_Einlagerung = NA_integer_, Zufriedenheit_Einlagerung = NA_integer_, 
Zufriedenheit_Einlagerung = NA_integer_, Zufriedenheit_Einlagerung = NA_integer_, 
Zufriedenheit_Einlagerung = NA_integer_, Zufriedenheit_Einlagerung = NA_integer_
), .Label = c("sehr gering", "gering", "mittel", "hoch", "sehr hoch", 
"keine Angabe", "NA"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My goal:

- sort values that are valid, exclude missings and those who choose not to reply in this column
- plot only the values, choose colour and and the number of displayed cases
- additionally I want to include a write comand so that I will have 110 bar charts in my working directory

Where I am stuck

```
for (i in 1:4) {
  test[,c(i)] <- factor((test[ ,c(i)]), levels = c("sehr gering" , "gering", "mittel", "hoch", "sehr hoch", "keine Angabe", "NA"))
  print(ggplot(data=subset.data.frame((test[ ,c(i)]) %in% c("sehr gering" , "gering", "mittel", "hoch", "sehr hoch")), aes(x=(test[ ,c(i)]))))  + 
    geom_bar(fill = "cornflowerblue", 
             color="black") +
    geom_text(aes(label=stat(count)), stat = "count", vjust=-.75) +
    labs(subtitle = paste("n gesamt: ", nrow(subset(test[ ,c(i)] %in% c("sehr gering" , "gering", "mittel", "hoch", "sehr hoch"))), y = "Häufigkeit")) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) }
```

This produces the error message:
`error in rep_len(TRUE, nrow(x)) : invalid 'length.out' value`.

Using ggplot (without print) and naming one variable is working. Any suggestions on how I could finally get this loop running is highly appreciated. I did not found sth. similar in the forum yet.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code -

- In `for` loop I pass column names instead of number.
- Used `[[]]` to subset the respective columns and change them to `factor`.
- Create `subset_data` as separate dataframe to make it easier to reuse.
- Use `.data` to refer to columns in `aes`.

```
library(ggplot2)

for (i in colnames(test)) {
  test[[i]] <- factor(test[[i]], levels = c("sehr gering" , "gering", "mittel", "hoch", "sehr hoch", "keine Angabe", "NA"))
  subset_data <- subset(test, test[[i]] %in% c("sehr gering" , "gering", "mittel", "hoch", "sehr hoch"))
  print(ggplot(data=subset_data, aes(x= .data[[i]]))  + 
    geom_bar(fill = "cornflowerblue", 
             color="black") +
    geom_text(aes(label=stat(count)), stat = "count", vjust=-.75) +
    labs(subtitle = paste("n gesamt: ", nrow(subset_data), y = "Häufigkeit")) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)) 
}
```

Comment: Dear Ronak - this is just the improvement I was looking for. I limited the number of columns with a [start:end] number in for (i in colnames(test[2:5])) so that I will not get a plot for my id variable. Thanks a lot.